# ejs multiple class names

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ejs

I have the following ejs file

```
<head>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/quizPage.css" />
<script src="/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.save_qn', function(){
    console.log("Hi i m inside save");
});
</script>
<input type="button" class="save_qn btn btn-primary center-block" value="Save"/>
```

For some reason, the save_qn class is not being recognized by the jQuery selector. If I remove the other three classes from the class attribute above, it works fine. The bootstrap.css file is available in the path I have used in the link tag above. Any help please?

This used to work when I had the file saved as .html. But I do not think the problem is because of the .ejs file format though. Please share your inputs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues here and they have nothing to do with EJS. BTW, there isn't any EJS used in your code.  :

1. When working with jQuery, use the jQuery Ready method to enclose all your jQuery logic such as selectors, event listeners etc. This is because you do not want your jQuery code to execute before the targeted DOM elements are loaded in and ready for use. By enclosing your jQuery code within the jQuery ready function as shown below, you ensure that DOM elements are available for jQuery to act upon.

   ```
   <script>
   $(function() {
       // all jQ code goes here
   });
   </script>
   ```

   OR using the ES 2015 arrow function notation :

   ```
   <script>
   $(() => {
       // all jQ code goes here
   });
   </script>
   ```
2. The second issue I noticed was that your script tag with the jQuery event listener was within the body of the page and not in the head. This works fine however, you should move this to the end of the body, right before the closing `</body>` tag. This also ensures that all HTML is at least loaded in and present before JavaScript attempts to take control/modify it.

Comment: Thanks that helped. Yes, this is just a portion of my ejs file. It does not have ejs tags in it. Also I realized that I had kept the Savebutton overlapping with the submit button and probably causing the issue. When I moved it little apart, the Save button got enabled. However, I have fixed both the issues you have highlighted above. Thanks for your help.